# DotNetNuke Control Bar Not going away

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a page in DotNetNuke that is showing the Control Bar to all users even though they should not see it.  You can see an example currently at - http://raywalker.csicms.com/ContactUs/tabid/2078/language/en-US/Default.aspx

please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue on this page (http://raywalker.csicms.com/ContactUs/tabid/2078/language/en-US/Default.aspx) is that you have at least one control where "All Users" have been marked as having "Edit" permissions.

You will want to validate the settings for each module on the page and remove the "Edit" permissions for all users.

Comment: thanks i actually found the issue right after i posted it, just never had time to come back and give the feedback.